# Подключение нескольких устройств по SPI Arduino

Tags: arduino, spi

Кто-нибудь сталкивался с подключениям нескольких SPI устройство к Arduino? Подскажите, как заставить оба устройства работать? Подключал к разным CS-пинам, всё  равно не работает одно, пока не отключишь второе.

Comment: Так и делаете: у каждого устройства CS пин должен быть привязан к разным пинам контроллера. В коде должно быть прописано, что у одного такой-то пин, у другого другой. Возможно у вас вообще не с SPI проблема, а с недостаточной мощностью источника питания (но это только догадка).

Comment: @insolor, проблема в SPI, т.к. при комментировании строк инициализации одного из устройств, второй начинает исправно инициализироваться и наоборот. Пины заданы отдельно (10 пин для передатчика, 4 пин для SD-карты), НО не получается ими управлять, даже если на 4 пин подаю digitalWrite(4, HIGH) - SD-карта всё равно инициализируется! Питание передатчика от аккумулятора реализовано. Может подскажете библиотеку где software SPI реализован достойно?

Comment: Вы и не должны пинами вручную управлять. Ручное включение пина SD никак не поможет - тогда SD будет просто реагировать и на сигналы для SD, и на сигналы для передатчика. Без схемы и кода ничего конкретного по вашему случаю нельзя сказать.

Answer (score 1):

> Пины заданы отдельно (10 пин для передатчика, 4 пин для SD-карты)

Если у вас один из стандартных вариантов плат (совместимых с UNO), то ошибка в использовании 10 пина.

Стандартная библиотека SPI принудительно использует пин с номером SS (см. pins_arduino.h) для активации ведомого. В случае UNO-совместимых плат это как раз 10-й.

Чтобы работали несколько устройств нужно делать так:

1. MOSI, MISO и SCK подключать соответственно к пинам 11, 12 и 13 соответственно.
2. Для SS (CS) использовать любой пин, кроме 10, 11, 12 и 13.
3. К 10 пину не подключать вообще ничего.

Comment: А как управлять тогда включением и отключением модулей? Принудительно HIGH или LOW подавать?

Comment: Да, принудительно подавать LOW на выбранный, остальные держать в состоянии HIGH. Вы выше писали, что так и делаете.

Comment: Вы забыли упомянуть, что MMC SPI реализация нарушает стандарты работы с SPI, так что тут надо быть аккуратнее с тем, как именно инициализировать устройства (идеально, не позволять одновременного доступа к ним, иными словами код должен оперировать *транзакциями*, а не низкоуровневыми *команда-ответ*).

Comment: К сведению: @insolor, см. мой комментарий выше :)